# How to debug Rails connection pool usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm running into issues with Sidekiq workers.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)
```

I am following recommendations about using `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` and a suitably large connection pool.

I want to find out if I'm exhausting the connection pool. I'm logging `size` and `connections.length` from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool`, but they stay at a constant size = 100 connections.length = 5. Which suggests that this isn't a resource leak issue.

My MySQL server is configured to allow up to 400 concurrent connections.

My Job ended up looking like this:

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default    
  rescue_from StandardError do |exception|
    # clear connections on exception. Not sure if this is a good idea or not.
    ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!    
  end

  def perform()
    logger.info "size"
    logger.info ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.instance_eval { @size }
    logger.info  "connections"
    logger.info ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.instance_eval { @connections }.length

    # Ensure connections come from connection pool.
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |conn|
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Is this the right way to diagnose what's causing this, whether it's resource starvation or leakage? Are there other techniques I can use to work out why this is happening?

Comment: What is the size of the connection pool defined in your `database.yml`? How many sidekiq worker threads do you use?

Comment: Pool is defined as 100, as shown in connection_pool.size, 25 workers.

Answer (score 14):

Try `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool#stat`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.stat 
# => { size: 15, connections: 1, busy: 1, dead: 0, idle: 0, waiting: 0, checkout_timeout: 5 }
```

From `connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb`, in activerecord 5.2.2.1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly I'm no longer in a position to try this.

Answer (score 8):

This `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` can in my opinion occur in only one scenario - when there are **so many threads wanting to use DB connections** that the pool is exhausted and even waiting for a free connection does not help (as learned from the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/107f4282bbfabc011d5ad3bcf3fb3c6fb812ad30/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L425)).

In your case, it is weird. You use only 25 worker threads but the pool is set to 100 connections, so there is plenty of reserve. I still suspect that you must have threads spawning somewhere. Perhaps you do some threading in your jobs? Perhaps you use a gem that creates threads in your jobs?

Anyway, if you are able to reproduce the exception, I would suggest to catch it and obtain the listing of all threads at the moment it occurs, something like this:

```
begin
  # job stuff...      
rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError
  puts "listing #{Thread.list.count} threads:"
  Thread.list.each_with_index do |t,i| 
    puts "---- thread #{i}: #{t.inspect}"
    puts t.backtrace.take(5)  
  end
end
```

I expect there will be 100 or more threads and you should see where exactly they are stuck from the backtrace.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I'll try that. I'm not spinning up any threads myself but who knows what other libraries are doing!

Comment: Did you find anything yet?

Comment: No. I reduced the number of sidekiq workers and have no errors. This is going in the long-term investigation list. Thanks for checking.